# R: Impute missing values from other categorical values in same vector

Tags: r

I have a large dataset and am trying to determine how to impute an existing categorical value (Seminar #) for a missing values in the same vector for the same Student #.  An example is below where the first observation of student "813" is missing his Seminar number, which should be "Sem5" according to the second observation.

```
Stu#  Sem#
812   Sem1
812   Sem1
813
813   Sem5
814   Sem9
814   Sem9
```

I've been at this a few hours and have note had any success.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: this package would be a good place to start: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a data frame where `Sem#` is character (if not, convert to character) and that the only possible values for Sem# are either blank or the correct seminar name, try:

```
df.ord <- df[order(nchar(df$Sem), decreasing=T), ]
merge(df, df.ord[!duplicated(df.ord$Stu), ], by="Stu", all.x=T)[c(1, 3)]
#   Stu Sem.y
# 1 812  Sem1
# 2 812  Sem1
# 3 813  Sem5
# 4 813  Sem5
# 5 814  Sem9
# 6 814  Sem9
```

Note I changed your column headers to avoid the `#`.

Basically, what I'm doing here is first re-ordering the data so that values with blank `Sem#` end up last, and then using `duplicated` to subset the data-frame just to non-duplicated values that have non-blank `Sem#` values.  Once we have that, we can just merge back to the original data to attach the `Sem#`.

Comment: Thanks BrodieG - I will try this approach and get back.

Comment: Brodie - This doesn't seem to be doing the job - I'm still left with observations that have no value for Seminar #.  The data is ordered for sure but the merge doesn't appear to be imputing the missing data.

Comment: @user3313875, can you post the section of the data that is causing the problem?  This will only work if for any Stu# that has an NA, there is another entry with the same Stu# that is not NA.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up Brodie - I've run into some other problems with the data that once I address them I should be good.